# Error decrypting file

Tags: c, ssl, encryption, blowfish

i encrypt a file using ideas from [tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue87/vinayak.html](http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue87/vinayak.html). I downloaded and compiled this source code for encrypting/decrypting a simple text file. Once compiled I do:

> `./blowfish input_file.txt output_enc.txt output_dec.txt`

I use the options:

1. `G` for generating a key
2. `E` for encrypting the file, so `output_enc.txt` is generated
3. `D` for decrypting `output_enc.txt` so `output_dec.txt` is generated

In the third step I obtain a segmentation fault. A decrypted file is generated but it differs in some characters from the original one. Any ideas?

Comment: Please give us some source code to go on. Perhaps from where you might think the segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: I'll second.  Without the code we're just shooting in the dark.  Here's an idea: try a smaller file to see if it still segfaults.  If it doesn't, then you've declared some buffer somewhere too small.

Comment: Hi, I tried to paste the code, but I can not.

Here the original small source file:

http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue87/misc/vinayak/sym_funcs.c.txt

Answer (score 1):

This question is very similar to the one I've answered previously. Did you search before posting the question?
Anyway here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993780/assistance-with-openssl-blowfish-simple-example-inserting-garbage-characters). The page you are using as source is wrong. Beware that the code I provided is only a corrected version of the original supplied code, and can be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

tried it on my machine, same result, I can only assume this was written to an older
Crypto lib, which the new one is incompatible with.
If it's of interest, the Segmentation fault is on line

```
 if (EVP_DecryptFinal (&ctx, outbuf + olen, &tlen) != 1)
```

Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
Access not within mapped region at address 0x808080C