# Encrypting a plain text file in C

Tags: c, linux, cryptography, encryption

I am currently writing a linux application in C that reads from a configuration file. This configuration file contains some data that I would like to encrypt so it is not plain text. I have spent hours researching this and have not found a viable solution. Since the application will need to read from the configuration I will need to be able to encrypt it and decrypt it on the fly. So far from research I really like openSSL crypto library. I know from the command line you can do:

openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.txt -out file.enc

If anyone can provide an example of how I can do this in C, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: http://www.rtfm.com/openssl-examples/

Comment: I hope you're aware that anyone who has access to the file involved can read the key file and use it to decrypt the text file. Who are you trying to hide the text file from? I suspect that your security model is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at the [O'Reilly-Book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596002701). There are a couple of examples on how to encrypt things. Unfortunately the most are for Network-Encryption.

I found an example in the book, but didnt test it:

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>

int main(int argc,  char *argv[])
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX  ctx;
    char            key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH];
    char            iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
    char            *ct, *out;
    char            final[EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    char            str[] = "123456789abcdef";
    int             i;
    if (!seed_prng())
    {
    printf("Fatal Error!  Unable to seed the PRNG!\n");
    abort();
    }
    select_random_key(key, EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH);
    select_random_iv(iv, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);
    EVP_EncryptInit(&ctx, EVP_bf_cbc(), key, iv);
    ct = encrypt_example(&ctx, str, strlen(str), &i);
    printf("Ciphertext is %d bytes.\n", i);
    EVP_DecryptInit(&ctx, EVP_bf_cbc(), key, iv);
    out = decrypt_example(&ctx, ct, 8);
    printf("Decrypted: >>%s<<\n", out);
    out = decrypt_example(&ctx, ct + 8, 8);
    printf("Decrypted: >>%s<<\n", out);
    if (!EVP_DecryptFinal(&ctx, final, &i))
    {
    printf("Padding incorrect.\n");
    abort();
    }
    final[i] = 0;
    printf("Decrypted: >>%s<<\n", final);
}

char *encrypt_example(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, char *data, int inl, int *rb) 
{
    char *ret;
    int i, tmp, ol;
    ol = 0;
    ret = (char *)malloc(inl + EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(ctx));
    for (i = 0; i < inl / 100; i++)
    {
    EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, &ret[ol], &tmp, &data[ol], 100);
    ol += tmp;
    }
    if (inl % 100)
    {
    EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, &ret[ol], &tmp, &data[ol], inl%100);
    ol += tmp;
    }
    EVP_EncryptFinal(ctx, &ret[ol], &tmp);
    *rb = ol + tmp;
    return ret;
}

char *decrypt_example(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, char *ct, int inl)
{
    /* We're going to null-terminate the plaintext under the assumption it's
     * non-null terminated ASCII text. The null can be ignored otherwise.
     */
    char *pt = (char *)malloc(inl + EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(ctx) + 1);
    int ol;
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, pt, &ol, ct, inl);
    if (!ol) /* there's no block to decrypt */
    {
    free(pt);
    return NULL;
    }
    pt[ol] = 0;
    return pt;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993780/assistance-with-openssl-blowfish-simple-example-inserting-garbage-characters/999151#999151) and check this [article](http://www.linuxforums.org/articles/security-programming-with-openssl-part-i_270.html).

You can replace `EVP_bf_cbc()` with `EVP_aes_128_cbc() EVP_aes_192_cbc() or EVP_aes_256_cbc()` depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need the SSL development packages.  (libssl-dev in Ubuntu).  Depending on how you implement it, you will also need libcrypto-dev.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a huge O'Reilly fan, but I found [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600270X) book to be very helpful when starting this type of thing for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do your own? Read enough bytes from dev/random (your key) and XOR the configuration file with it. To decrypt, XOR again with the same key. This is simple,fast,and secure. No complicated libraries needed.

Comment: You should never ever write your own crypto. Never. Ever.