# How to save pictures in MySQL

Tags: mysql, c

I want to save pictures(mostly JPEG) to MySQL database. I saw most people say save pictures elsewhere and add link to table. It is the most efficient way. But i need to encrypt my pictures and want to set user privileges. So how can i do this. Please can anyone help me.

I'm using a C client program to connect to the MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a good idea, but if you really have to do it this way, use BLOBs (a data type).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Comment: The database will have more than 1000 entries. Will this slow queries.

Comment: Yes it will, and the base will be huge. You can keep encypted files out of the database (somewhere in filesystem, for example) anyway. This should not affect security.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, do not insert pictures to the database table. It reduces manageability heavility. Also, when the database increases, the performance is reduced significantly. Let **DBMS manage data and let File Management System manage files**.
Better, save the pictures on a table and then later only retrieve the images from a folder, once a valid user is found.

Comment: But how can i encrypt the pictures.

Comment: You are asking too many questions. It's not a forum thread. Your question (how to save pictures in MySQL) has been answered. Google for answers or post your other questions as new ones.

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA, Why do you need to encrypt the picture any way? Encryption can be done on low level I guess... may be googling might find a better result. May be question like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348263/encrypting-a-plain-text-file-in-c can give you a heads up.

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA, Is right about posting new questions for every other questions you have? "How to encrypt a image file in C?" is another question and you should post them as another question to get better answers on them.

Comment: @Starx Yes i will find a way. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BLOB data type for the field in which to put the raw data (the encrypted one) - However, I don't recommend that - when you have full table scans, your queries will be very slow

Comment: Is there any other efficient way.

Comment: If done wisely, this could work, actually. Such database can grow very quickly, and that is worse. But we don't know the case, and it seems that he has been warned, so...