# Trouble Using with EVP_ENCRYPT Usage

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, corruption

Hi I am trying to write a program that uses the EVP_Encrypt Openssl libraries but I am having some trouble.  I used the post [Assistance with openssl blowfish simple example inserting garbage characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993780/assistance-with-openssl-blowfish-simple-example-inserting-garbage-characters) as a guide thinking that it should give me a good starting point.  However, I'm pretty sure something is going wrong but I can't find out what.  I know something is wrong because I use openssl to test whether or not ciphertext can be decrypted.  The command is: `cat file.enc | openssl bf-cbc -d -K cafefacedeadbeef -iv 0 > output` where `file.enc` is the file of ciphertext created by my program.  After running the Openssl command I get this error message `bad decrypt
7418:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:330:`  This problem might be related to the fact I'm trying to 0 out the initialization vector or the way I am reading in the key but I am not positive.  Any help would be great.

Encrypt function:

```
void encrypt(unsigned char *key, unsigned char* msg)
{
        unsigned char iv[8]={0};

        int length = 0;
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX enc_struct;
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&enc_struct);
        EVP_EncryptInit(&enc_struct, EVP_bf_cbc(), key, iv);

        unsigned char* out = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 1024 +EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH);

        if (EVP_EncryptUpdate(&enc_struct, out, &length, msg, 8) != 1)
        {
                printf("error update\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        write(STDOUT_FILENO, out, length);

        int temp_length = 0;

        if(EVP_EncryptFinal(&enc_struct, out+length, &temp_length) !=1)
        {
                printf("error final\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        write(STDOUT_FILENO, out+length, temp_length);

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&enc_struct);

        free(out);
}
```

The calling of the encrypt function and reading in the key.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        setprogname("bf");
        setproctitle("-%s", "bf");
        int decrypt_flag = 0;
        int encrypt_flag = 0;
        int key_flag = 0;
        char ch;
        unsigned char raw_key[16] = {'\0'};

        if (argc <=1)
              help();
        memcpy(raw_key, argv[optind], 24);

        bytes_read = read(STDIN_FILENO, msg, 8);
        if (encrypt_flag)
                encrypt(raw_key, msg);
        else
                decrypt();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that you need to use the openssl specific method of deriving a key... It's called [EVP_BytesToKey](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html)